# lambda expression prevents class from spring component-scan

Tags: java, spring, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Our Application have Class Test with @Component annotation.
Lambda expression is being used here.

```
    @Component
    public class Test{

      private ScheduledExecutorService schedulerExecutorService;
      private long timeoutForRollBack=180000;
      private long timeoutFailoverDelay=180000;
      public static Test getInstance() {
         if (INSTANCE == null) {
/*Actual instance will be created via reflection. using new for understanding */
             INSTANCE = new Test();
         }
        return INSTANCE;
      }
      public void handleFailOver(){
            schedulerExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                 () -> {
                           schedulerExecutorService.shutdown();                               
                        }, 
                  timeoutForRollBack, timeoutFailoverDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      }

    }
```

But this Test class bean is not created. But when this method is commented, then the Test class bean is created.

Using Java 8 oracle and Eclipse Neon2.

Suggest if any changes needed to fix this.

> Edit 1:
>
> ---

Found similar issue reported:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3732

> Edit 2:
>
> ---
>
> Similar issue faced https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda/issues/121

P.S:

if

```
() -> {
                           schedulerExecutorService.shutdown();                               
                        }
```

is replaced with private innerclass, this is working fine.

```
private class TerminalScheduledExecutor implements Runnable{
@Override
        public void run() {
            schedulerExecutorService.shutdown();
        }
}.
```

However looking forward for solutions without replacing lambda functions.

Comment: Instead of a snippet post the full class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had provided modified code snippet. could not post complete class. let me edit post with more details

Comment: Just tried but can't reproduce your problem with spring 4.2.6, which version are your using?

Comment: @shizhz  we are using 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: I suggest you tidy up your code - there is no need for a getInstance() method and also schedulerExecutorService doesn't appear to be injected so it will be null.

Comment: Is is possible shutdown is calling System.exit or throwing a RuntimeException? Also, (() -> { schedulerExecutorService.shutdown(); })  could just be (()-> schedulerExecutorService.shutdown())
 or even (schedulerExecutorService::shutdown)

Comment: which version of spring you are on?

Comment: @AkshayKhopkar 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Does your application startup fail, or it just silently ignores your `Test` bean? Is there anything in the logs? Did you try other spring versions (like 4.2.x)?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy we are accessing this Test Class during startup and we are receiving null for the instance of Test.

Comment: I created a test case with 4.1.1 and unfortunately could not reproduce your issue. Have you tried to change spring framework's logging level for detailed bean creation logs? Additionally if you're using maven's compiler plugin could you please make sure that its not something below 1.8?

Comment: @OnurAktaş Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change spring framework's logging level for detailed bean creation logs?

*per suggestion here:* [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution at last:

Issue was with

> org.reflections.Reflections

version. Upgraded it to

> 0.9.9-RC2

and the issue is resolved.

As per @OnurAktaş suggestions, enabled debug and found that

> could not scan file error occurred in org.reflections.reflection.